# подскажите в чем ошибка JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, frontend

нужно сделать dropdown menu, при нажатии на стрелочку меню появляется на долю секунды и возвращается обратно. Как это можно исправить?

```js
const bars = document.querySelector("#bars"),
  strengthDiv = document.querySelector("#strength"),
  passwordInput = document.querySelector("#password");

const strength = {
  1: "weak",
  2: "medium",
  3: "strong",
};

const getIndicator = (password, strengthValue) => {
  for (let index = 0; index < password.length; index++) {
    let char = password.charCodeAt(index);
    if (!strengthValue.upper && char >= 65 && char <= 90) {
      strengthValue.upper = true;
    } else if (!strengthValue.numbers && char >= 48 && char <= 57) {
      strengthValue.numbers = true;
    } else if (!strengthValue.lower && char >= 97 && char <= 122) {
      strengthValue.lower = true;
    }
  }

  let strengthIndicator = 0;

  for (let metric in strengthValue) {
    if (strengthValue[metric] === true) {
      strengthIndicator++;
    }
  }

  return strength[strengthIndicator] ?? "";
};

const getStrength = (password) => {
  let strengthValue = {
    upper: false,
    numbers: false,
    lower: false,
  };

  return getIndicator(password, strengthValue);
};

const handleChange = () => {
  let { value: password } = passwordInput;

  console.log(password);

  const strengthText = getStrength(password);

  bars.classList = "";

  if (strengthText) {
    strengthDiv.innerText = `${strengthText} Password`;
    bars.classList.add(strengthText);
  } else {
    strengthDiv.innerText = "";
  }
};


const dropMenu = () => {
  const headerEl = document.querySelector('.material-symbols-outlined')
  const drop = document.querySelector(".menu-drop")
  headerEl.classList.toggle('rotate')
  drop.classList.toggle("menu-open")
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  html,
  body,
  .wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(98.06deg, #158FFF 43.8%, #B0F0FF 129.45%);
  }
  
  @keyframes rotate {
    100% {
      background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
  }
  
  body {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 200vh;
    font-family: "helvetica";
    color: #868b94;
    animation: rotate 5s infinite alternate linear;
  }
  
  button {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .control {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 16px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    margin: 8px 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  
  .login-card {
    width: 32%;
    padding: 100px 30px 32px;
    border-radius: 1.25rem;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    backdrop-filter: blur(26px);
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .login-card > h2 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 6px;
    color: #f9f9f9;
  }
  
  .login-card img {
    height: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  }
  
  .login-card > h3 {
    color: #837f90;
    margin: 0 0 40px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  
  .login-form {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
  }
  
  .login-form input.control::placeholder {
    color: #868b94;
  }
  
  .login-form > button.control {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 56px;
    padding: 0 16px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    color: #000000;
    border: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: all 0.375s;
  }
  
  .username {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  @keyframes spin {
    100% {
      rotate: 1turn;
    }
  }
  
  .spinner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 16px;
    translate: 0 -50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #ccc9e1;
    border-top-color: #8f44fd;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
  }
  
  .spinner.visible {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .indicator {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  #bars {
    margin: 8px 0;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 8px;
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  
  #bars div {
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    width: 0%;
  }
  
  #bars.weak div {
    background: #bc2b38;
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  
  #bars.medium div {
    background: #d36f30;
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  
  #bars.strong div {
    background: #1eb965;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .strength {
    text-align: left;
    height: 30px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }





.dropdown {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    color: #868b94;
}

.menu-drop {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 0.5rem;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 8px;
        outline: none;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 1rem;
        height: auto;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        border-radius: 6px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        font-family: inherit;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 16px;
        transition: 0.4s;
    
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.rotate {
    transform: rotate(0.5turn);
}

.menu-close {
    display: none;
}

.menu-open {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
  <head>
    <title>Signup 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/registration/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="login-card">
      <h2>Регистрация</h2>
      <h3>Введите свои данные</h3>
      <form class="login-form">
        <div class="username">
          <input
            autocomplete="off"
            spellcheck="false"
            class="control"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Ваше имя"
          />
          <div id="spinner" class="spinner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="username">
          <input
            autocomplete="off"
            spellcheck="false"
            class="control"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email"
          />
          <div id="spinner" class="spinner"></div>
        </div>
        <input
          spellcheck="false"
          class="control"
          id="password"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Пароль"
          onkeyup="handleChange()"
        />
        <input
          spellcheck="false"
          class="control"
          id="password2"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Подтвердите пароль"
          onkeyup="handleChange()"
        />
        
        <div class="number">
          <input
            autocomplete="off"
            spellcheck="false"
            class="control"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Ваш номер"
          />
          <div id="spinner" class="spinner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown username control">
          <div>Кто размещает?</div>
          <button id="drop-js" onclick="dropMenu()"><span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="arrow">
            arrow_drop_down
          </span></button>
            
        </div>
        <div class="control menu-drop menu-close">
          <div>Агенство</div>
          <div>Застройщик</div>
          <div>Риелтор</div>
          <div>Собственник</div>
        </div>


        <div id="bars">
          <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="strength" id="strength"></div>

       

        
        <button class="control" type="button">Далее</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/registration/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> при нажатии на стрелочку меню появляется на долю секунды и возвращается обратно. Как это можно исправить?

У тебя та кнопка считается "сабмидной" и перезагружает форму...

```
<button id="drop-js" onclick="dropMenu()"><span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="arrow">
```

Сделай ее "простой"

```
<button id="drop-js" type='button' onclick="dropMenu()"><span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="arrow">
```

Или иначе подходи к вопросы обработчиков событий. ;)

```js
const bars = document.querySelector("#bars"),
  strengthDiv = document.querySelector("#strength"),
  passwordInput = document.querySelector("#password");

const strength = {
  1: "weak",
  2: "medium",
  3: "strong",
};

const getIndicator = (password, strengthValue) => {
  for (let index = 0; index < password.length; index++) {
    let char = password.charCodeAt(index);
    if (!strengthValue.upper && char >= 65 && char <= 90) {
      strengthValue.upper = true;
    } else if (!strengthValue.numbers && char >= 48 && char <= 57) {
      strengthValue.numbers = true;
    } else if (!strengthValue.lower && char >= 97 && char <= 122) {
      strengthValue.lower = true;
    }
  }

  let strengthIndicator = 0;

  for (let metric in strengthValue) {
    if (strengthValue[metric] === true) {
      strengthIndicator++;
    }
  }

  return strength[strengthIndicator] ?? "";
};

const getStrength = (password) => {
  let strengthValue = {
    upper: false,
    numbers: false,
    lower: false,
  };

  return getIndicator(password, strengthValue);
};

const handleChange = () => {
  let { value: password } = passwordInput;

  console.log(password);

  const strengthText = getStrength(password);

  bars.classList = "";

  if (strengthText) {
    strengthDiv.innerText = `${strengthText} Password`;
    bars.classList.add(strengthText);
  } else {
    strengthDiv.innerText = "";
  }
};


const dropMenu = () => {
  const headerEl = document.querySelector('.material-symbols-outlined')
  const drop = document.querySelector(".menu-drop")
  headerEl.classList.toggle('rotate')
  drop.classList.toggle("menu-open")
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  html,
  body,
  .wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(98.06deg, #158FFF 43.8%, #B0F0FF 129.45%);
  }
  
  @keyframes rotate {
    100% {
      background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
  }
  
  body {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 200vh;
    font-family: "helvetica";
    color: #868b94;
    animation: rotate 5s infinite alternate linear;
  }
  
  button {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .control {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 16px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    margin: 8px 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  
  .login-card {
    width: 32%;
    padding: 100px 30px 32px;
    border-radius: 1.25rem;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    backdrop-filter: blur(26px);
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .login-card > h2 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 6px;
    color: #f9f9f9;
  }
  
  .login-card img {
    height: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  }
  
  .login-card > h3 {
    color: #837f90;
    margin: 0 0 40px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  
  .login-form {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
  }
  
  .login-form input.control::placeholder {
    color: #868b94;
  }
  
  .login-form > button.control {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 56px;
    padding: 0 16px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    color: #000000;
    border: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: all 0.375s;
  }
  
  .username {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  @keyframes spin {
    100% {
      rotate: 1turn;
    }
  }
  
  .spinner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 16px;
    translate: 0 -50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #ccc9e1;
    border-top-color: #8f44fd;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
  }
  
  .spinner.visible {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .indicator {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  #bars {
    margin: 8px 0;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 8px;
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  
  #bars div {
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    width: 0%;
  }
  
  #bars.weak div {
    background: #bc2b38;
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  
  #bars.medium div {
    background: #d36f30;
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  
  #bars.strong div {
    background: #1eb965;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .strength {
    text-align: left;
    height: 30px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }





.dropdown {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    color: #868b94;
}

.menu-drop {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 0.5rem;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 8px;
        outline: none;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 1rem;
        height: auto;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        border-radius: 6px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        font-family: inherit;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 16px;
        transition: 0.4s;
    
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.rotate {
    transform: rotate(0.5turn);
}

.menu-close {
    display: none;
}

.menu-open {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
  <head>
    <title>Signup 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/registration/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="login-card">
      <h2>Регистрация</h2>
      <h3>Введите свои данные</h3>
      <form class="login-form">
        <div class="username">
          <input
            autocomplete="off"
            spellcheck="false"
            class="control"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Ваше имя"
          />
          <div id="spinner" class="spinner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="username">
          <input
            autocomplete="off"
            spellcheck="false"
            class="control"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email"
          />
          <div id="spinner" class="spinner"></div>
        </div>
        <input
          spellcheck="false"
          class="control"
          id="password"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Пароль"
          onkeyup="handleChange()"
        />
        <input
          spellcheck="false"
          class="control"
          id="password2"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Подтвердите пароль"
          onkeyup="handleChange()"
        />
        
        <div class="number">
          <input
            autocomplete="off"
            spellcheck="false"
            class="control"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Ваш номер"
          />
          <div id="spinner" class="spinner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown username control">
          <div>Кто размещает?</div>
          <button id="drop-js" type='button' onclick="dropMenu()"><span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="arrow">
            arrow_drop_down
          </span></button>
            
        </div>
        <div class="control menu-drop menu-close">
          <div>Агенство</div>
          <div>Застройщик</div>
          <div>Риелтор</div>
          <div>Собственник</div>
        </div>


        <div id="bars">
          <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="strength" id="strength"></div>

       

        
        <button class="control" type="button">Далее</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/registration/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```